# Is there any way to get the list of all users who are currently logged into Quickbooks in C# .NET?

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to integrate QuickBooks with our company application. We want to get the list of users who are currently logged into QuickBooks. Is that possible? How to get that list using C# .NET? I know its possible from the QuickBooks by accessing the Company->Users->View Users. But is there a way to get that list to display in our application?

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000046/where-to-start-with-quickbooks-development and Google in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, none of the available QuickBooks APIs support this.